# Run android manifest merger as a stand-alone application

Tags: android, gradle, ant, build, android-manifest

I have `Ant` project with many modules.
I'm trying to merge some modules into bigger ones and reduce their numbers.

Can I run `android manifest merger` as a stand-alone application and merge manifests specified as arguments?

For example i have modules:
**A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **E**

I need to **[A]**, **[B]** become **[AB]** module, and **[C]**, **[D]**, **[E]** to become **[CDE]**

I need this because I'm writing `Python` script, which will help migrate to `Gradle`. Script will scan directories, and create new project with all files, copied classes and resources. I would like it to be universal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I would like to answer my own question.

`manifest-merger` is `java` library placed in `ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/manifest-merger.jar`

To use `jar` as stand-alone application, I cloned project from `google platform tools` repository:
`git clone --depth=1 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base`

Manifst-Merger source code is place under `base/build-system/manifest-merger`

Also you can find code at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.tools.build/manifest-merger/24.3.0).

I extracted code into `maven` project, resolved all external dependencies and created project which can be cloned and use as stand-alone application:

https://github.com/Bresiu/android-manifest-merger

Usage:

1. `git clone git@github.com:Bresiu/android-manifest-merger.git`
2. `mvn install`
3. `java -jar target/manifest-merger-jar-with-dependencies.jar  --main mainAndroidManifest.xml
   --log [VERBOSE, INFO, WARNING, ERROR]
   --libs [path separated list of lib's manifests]
   --overlays [path separated list of overlay's manifests]
   --property [PACKAGE | VERSION_CODE | VERSION_NAME | MIN_SDK_VERSION | TARGET_SDK_VERSION | MAX_SDK_VERSION=value]
   --placeholder [name=value]
   --out [path of the output file]`
4. I have used this library as follows:

`java -jar target/manifest-merger-jar-with-dependencies.jar --main <path_to_main_manifest> --libs <path_to_libs_manifests_divided by ':'> --out <output_manifest> --log WARNING`

Comment: thanks for this. after installing maven, adding `JAVA_HOME`, seems to work.  however, got message _"`Error: Invalid parameter :, expected a command switch`"_ when trying to use `--libs`.  I am in cygwin bash...

Comment: I found that I have to use the semi-colon (';') as a separator, rather than the colon (':')